# using Newtonsoft.Json in c# not working even after downloading package

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I downloaded Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2 package by package manager console,
and it certainly showed that the package is installed in project.
However, when I try to use the package

```
using Newtonsoft.Json
```

visual studio keeps warning me the name is not found and draws red underline.
What should I do? uninstalling and reinstalling the package didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference by clicking on your project in the solution explorer with right click -> References -> Newtonsoft Json.
Add it and compile.

Comment: what do you mean clicking on my project?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected same project while installing package

[image]

Comment: package is installed in Assembly-Csharp, Assembly-Csharp-Editor, Assembly-Csharp-firstpass.
Does the default project has to be set to my own unity project name?
but only choices I can see when I click Default project: button all I see is above three projects.

Comment: Yes, and after successfully installation of package make sure given package name is shown in References.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, i notice that i have some bll files that have been installed

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
- Newtonsoft.Json
- Newtonsoft.Json.b..

i removed all the files exept 'Newtonsoft.Json' closed the vs.code reopened it and it worked!

Comment: Did you notice  the question date?

Comment: I hade the same issue, when I was looking for answers this one come out. When I got the issue fixed I wanted everyone that run in to it will have it like i was supposed too!